# FL Studio 12 - How To Create An Overlay (Double) Effect With Your Voice

Tags: voice, effects, fl-studio

In many songs, this song for example -

namely from 00:54 to 01:52 also -

namely from 00:15 to 00:50 (I know there's many others that I know of these were just the few that were on the top of my head), there's an overlay effect with the artists voices and I've been wanting to create that type of effect in FL Studio, now I understand if the artist is singing normally then using falsetto or singing with another artist you can easily just place one track beneath the first to create this effect but in some songs and sections it sounds as if they are using the exact same voice to amplify the artists voice in that certain section which sounds almost like a overlay effect to me, if this sounds very vague and I need to explain a little more let me know.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few different ways to do this.  The simplest way is to double the existing vocal track, and then shift the copy slightly in pitch (by a few cents) and/or time (10-20 ms).  You could also shift one towards the left channel and the other towards the right to gain more seeming independence of the voices.

Applying a compression effect can also help create this kind of sound, which sounds like what is being done in the first clip you linked.  (In the second it actually sounds like separate recordings to me.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the well thought out and detailed explanation of this vocal process.

Comment: Multiple takes (up to 6 or 7) of the same vocal part, spread over the stereo field (from hard left to hard right going through intermediate pisitions) is a common production technique to give more presence to a vocal part without without making it sound artificial. I believe that's the case with the MJ track, as you say, although I cannot tell how many takes are bring used. MJ was reportedly a perfectionist and tremendously perfect in his vocal lines, so multiple takes would sound almost indistinguishable, but the infinitesimal differences would be enough to enrich the sound.

Comment: Regarding the JB sound it seems to me that auto tuning is also being used.

Answer (score 1):

You need two copies of the same audio file to do this in fl studio.

key: track A and track A(copy)

- Put track A in the playlist then copy it in edison
- add the blur effect with a little amount of between 100 - 300 ms to the track(track A copy) in edison
- drag track A(copy) under Track a in the playlist then check if yours satisfied with the sound
- I you are not satisfied, send both tracks to the mixer insert
- Put the fruity reverb2 in track A. set the reverb to a  medium room size, dry level up then wet level and early reflection below half.
- Also add a delay to track A with a time of one second and reduce the delay volume to about half
- Add swap stereo effect to both tracks from the channel rack settings.

There is no Fixed way to approach this effect, but you should get what you need along each step. Also don't follow the exact values of things I've given you, as this is what works for me and we both don't have the same audio file so what works for me might not work for you. But i hope it helps you.